# UIFocus.h file not found/Could not build Objective-C Module 'UIKit'

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, xcode

Currently I am trying to implement `OpenCV` into a Swift 3 project. To do so I have created a bridging header and Objective-C wrappers. However, when I go to run the code that I have, the project can't build the `UIKit` module because it can't find the `UIFocus.h` file. (My version of Xcode 8.2.1)

I have tried deleting derived data and making sure that I have the proper frameworks linked.

How do I get Xcode to find the `UIFocus.h` file? Or is there any other way I could get the `UIKit` module to build?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I accidentally edited the UIKit file. I gave it the proper path and now it works.